# Creating Log-In Page for backend server

Tags: php, jquery, html, server

I've used Custom CSS and JS plug in to add gamesparks html and js to the page.  You can visit it at www.martialparks.com

I'm trying to initialize the sdk with the intent to send and receive authentication requests with my gamesparks server (at least.)  When I enter my API key and secret...nothing happens.

I feel like something should happen.

When I inspect the page, I found a few errors (I think.)

JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1
(index):42 GET my gamesparks.js link net::ERR_ABORTED
(index):43 GET my second gamesparks.js net::ERR_ABORTED
(index):44 GET my third gamesparks.js net::ERR_ABORTED
(index):59 Uncaught ReferenceError: GameSparks is not defined
    at (index):59
(anonymous) @ (index):59
(index):201 Uncaught ReferenceError: GameSparks is not defined
    at (index):201

But I don't know java.  Or HTML.

So I have no idea if those are even errors.

I'm pretty good at learning autonomously, and trouble shooting, but this is beyond me.

Anyone care to give me some input on what I should be doing???

Comment: If there are errors in your browser console the issue is javascript related. You should make sure that your javascript libraries are loaded and are in the correct order if something is 'not defined'. Also you should direct your queries to 'GameSparks' as this is not Wordpress related and is off topic here.

Comment: The fact that the js is gamesparks seems irrelevant to me.  I could have had any random js added.

Comment: I will attempt to reorder the loading sequence of the js and see if that helps.  I've also noticed that it attempts to find the js at my website/whatever.js.  I'm not sure exactly where to save the js files in my wordpress file manager.  wp-content?  Do I have to?  I thought I could just include javascript as part of the wordpress, without having to save random js files in the file manager.

Comment: Update:  I went through the code and found that each of the three javascripts were in order.  Nothing is referenced before it exists.  All variables are defined first.  It looks like the java is just not loading.

Comment: Update:  So I uploaded the javascript to different file paths.  wp-admin/js, and public.  Neither of those places are referenced, apparently.  This thing is looking for my javascript, I just have no idea where to put it!  I think once it finds it, it will then be able to define that crazy variable too.

Comment: Update:  Because I'm using the Custom CSS & JS plug in, I made sure to enable correct permissions on wp-content/uploads/custom-css-js, then copied the three js's there, thinking maybe the plugin had changed my default directory somehow?  That didn't work either.

Comment: Oh my... You need to add your javascript files to your theme. 'wp-content/themes/your_theme_name'. Just google how to edit my Wordpress theme, there are literally pages of tutorials

Comment: Not a bad thought, Nath!  I copied and pasted the files to that exact directory.  (I use the blank-slate theme.)  Again, same errors popped up.  I made sure they were the correct files, the most recent versions, and the filenames were correct.  All checks out.  Yet, I'm getting those same errors.  When I highlight for details, it gives me a filepath of myurl/whatever.js  I'm not sure to change the url it references, or even what the url would be if I save my js files in the theme folder.  Nothing is working, and I hate my life.

Comment: You need to edit your header.php or functions.php file in your theme. And seriously you should google: how to edit my Wordpress theme you will learn so much!

Comment: I edited my header.php to include: <script type="text/javascript" src="gamesparks.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="gamesparks-functions.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="hmac-sha256.js"></script>     Yet I still get a 404 error.  I really truly feel that it is looking in the wrong spot, but I have no idea where to make it look!

Comment: I've also created a folder for the scripts within the theme and referenced them using this template:  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/scriptsfolder/script.js"></script>      That didn't work.  So I tried copying the scripts into jquery, and js folders.  That didn't work.  Still a 404.

Answer (score 0):

VICTORY.  At least...no 404 anymore.  I haven't actually tried to use the script yet, too excited.  Thanks for the direction, Nath!

Here is what I did.  I went to my theme and created a subfolder titled, "js."  In the same theme, I edited header.php to include the following just below :

(The part in bold, I just changed to whatever exact js I wanted.)

I reloaded the page and used my inspect element thing on my browser, and still had errors!  But then I remembered I was using the old stupid references somewhere.  I deleted them and...there we go.  New reference in, new subfolder...let me try to see if the java actually works...stand by...

No, it doesn't.

But that will end up under a totally different topic.  I know what I just did was elementary to you hardened WPressers, but for someone who has never done this...I'm pleased with myself.

Now on to figure out why the javascript isn't bouncing off my backend server!